# How to deserialize TcpClient response to json

Tags: c#, json, tcpclient

I am busy integrating application with a fiscal device that uses tcp connection. When i send data to it and i get the response back and i try deserialize it using json it does not work. here is my tcp client and the data of the response that i am trying to deserialize using json. the documentation said the response is json format but there seems to be some formatting issues. Would appreciate it if you could show me the best way to deserialize the response.

TCP Client

```
        private String Send(byte[] hexData)
    {
        byte[] data = hexData; // Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ConvertHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hexData)));
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ConvertHex(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hexData)));
             String response = String.Empty ;
                  
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect("192.168.8.98", 8888);
                    client.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Sent");
                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[100024];
                    String responseData = String.Empty;
                    Int32 bytes = client.GetStream().Read(receiveData, 0, receiveData.Length);
                    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData, 0, bytes);
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
                               
                var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESD.GetStatusResponse>(response);
                
            return response;
    }
```

Response data that i am trying to Deserialize as you can see above. on the deserialize part where i get the error. The Get StatusReponse Class matches the documentation and i can see some of properties in the data below.

> \u001a]\u0002\0\0\u0006?{\n\t"HardwareVersion":\t"2.0",\n\t"SoftwareVersion":\t"1.042",\n\t"SerialNumber":\t"100100003505",\n\t"Manufacture":\t"Inspur",\n\t"Model":\t"IS-100",\n\t"TPIN":\t"1001749833",\n\t"TaxpayerName":\t"ZAMBIA SHOE COMPANY PLC",\n\t"Addreess":\t"PLOT NO. 6007, MUKWA ROAD, INDUSTRIAL AREA",\n\t"ESDTime":\t"20210918180305",\n\t"TerminalID":\t"010300000051",\n\t"isInitialized":\ttrue,\n\t"isLocked":\tfalse,\n\t"MonitoringInfo":\t{\n\t\t"OfflineNum":\t0,\n\t\t"SingleAmount":\t0,\n\t\t"MonthlyInvoiceQuantity":\t0,\n\t\t"MonthlyCreditNoteAmount":\t0,\n\t\t"InvoiceHoldingQuantity":\t20,\n\t\t"RemainThreshold":\t20,\n\t\t"MonthlyCreditNoteNum":\t0\n\t},\n\t"TaxInfo":\t[{\n\t\t\t"TaxType":\t"01",\n\t\t\t"Category":\t[{\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t1,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"A",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"STANDARD RATED",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0.16,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t2,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"B",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"MTVs",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0.16,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t3,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"C1",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"EXPORT",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t4,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"C2",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"PRIVILEGED PERSONS",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t5,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"C3",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"ZERO RATED",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\t\t"CategoryId":\t6,\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxLabel":\t"D",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxName":\t"EXEMPT",\n\t\t\t\t\t"TaxRate":\t0,\n\t\t\t\t\t"EffectiveDate":\t"2018-01-10",\n\t\t\t\t\t"ExpiredDate":\t"2031-01-01"\n\t\t\t\t}]\n\t\t}]\n}\0Y:

Here is the GetStatusReponse class

```
        public class GetStatusResponse
    {
        public string HardwareVersion { get; set; }
        public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Manufacture { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string TPIN { get; set; }
        public string TaxpayerName { get; set; }
        public string Addreess { get; set; }
        public string ESDTime { get; set; }
        public string TerminalID { get; set; }
        public bool isInitialized { get; set; }
        public bool isLocked { get; set; }
        public Monitoringinfo MonitoringInfo { get; set; }
        public Taxinfo[] TaxInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. All i did is clean the response then deserialized it.

```
        public static string CleanResponse(string value)
    {
        int firstbrace = value.IndexOf('{');
        string res = value.Substring(firstbrace);
        int lastbrace = res.LastIndexOf('}');
        res = res.Substring(0, lastbrace + 1);
        return res; 
    }
```

Then here is what i did with the response

```
response = Helper.CleanResponse(response);

var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetStatusResponse>(response);
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could work since there's no curly brace in the data the OP posted.  CleanResponse is going to fail becauuse the firstBrace is going to be an index out of range at -1.